# PHP/MySQL Selecionar total do saldo de 1 cliente na tabela

Tags: php, mysql, select

O meu cliente JOSÉ aparece 4 vezes nessa tabela, e eu queria pegar o total do saldo dele. Como eu faço isso?

```
tabela "clientes"
ID    NOME    SALDO
1     josé     10
1     josé     20
1     josé     30
4     maria    50
5     marta    60
1     josé     100
7     ana      70
8     sara     80

Total de JOSÉ: 160
```

Eu gostaria que fosse uma consulta simples assim:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_login FROM clientes ????????? WHERE ID = 1");
```

Comment: Só pra constar, `ID = 'josé'` não traria nada porque "josé" é o `nome`; `id` é um inteiro :p

Comment: Obrigado pela observação, eu realmente errei, o correto seria ID = 1

Comment: IDs repetidas? Se isto for autoincrement é algo impossivel e a tua tabela não faz sentido. Me diga isto que esta fazendo é com JOIN?

Comment: Essa parte das IDs foi um erro na hora de digitar, por favor, desconsiderem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a função "sum" para somar valores de um determinado campo:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT sum(saldo) FROM clientes WHERE ID = 1");
```

**Edit:**

Se o campo "ID" conter uma chave primária (PK), você deve buscar pelo nome:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT sum(saldo) FROM clientes WHERE NOME = 'josé'");
```